# How can I get array_replace_recursive to treat numerically indexed array as a value?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using `array_replace_recursive` as a way of creating a cascading configuration system, but I have one problem with it: it treats a numerically indexed array as an array to recurse into, rather than a value:

```
$a = [
   'tournaments' => [
       'modes' => ['single', 'double', 'round-robin']
   ]
];

$b = [
   'tournaments' => [
       'modes' => ['single']
   ]
];

$c = [
   'tournaments' => [
       'modes' => ['double']
   ]
];

$result = array_replace_recursive($a, $b, $c);
```

returns

```
[
   'tournaments' => [
        0 => 'double',
        1 => 'double',
        2 => 'round-robin'
    ]
]
```

What I actually want:

```
[
   'tournaments' => [
        0 => 'double'
    ]
]
```

I could write my own alternative to `array_replace_recursive`, but I also want to keep it variadic, which becomes more complex. Is there any way to treat the `'modes'` setting as a plain "list" value rather than array that `array_replace_recusive` recurses into?

EDIT: I feel like this is one situation where the all-in-one flexibility of PHP arrays is actually a detriment rather than a benefit. Would be so nice if PHP had a plain list that was treated as a simple value (but could still be iterated over).

Comment: When you have an array element, do you always want to entirely replace it? Will you ever have more than 2 levels of nesting? If not I would not recurse on it and only replace on the outer array.

Comment: Yes, this is meant for a configuration system, so it will have several nested layers of configurations.

Comment: SO can you talk to how this will actually be used in your system?  My guess is that you should possibly be using objects here instead of associative arrays and possibly might want to consider using JSON as the storage medium for your config entries, for easy conversion appropriate data structures (object or arrays).  Is the problem that some properties should be overwritten by latter config entries?

Comment: You could use something like a pipe-delimited string `'single|double|round-robin'` then split those up when retrieving config values.  ... Assuming it would only ever be the inner-most endpoints accessed as config values.

Comment: There are a number of libraries that also do configuration management in PHP (like Zend\Config) for instance. You may consider taking a look at these rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @MikeBrant It's a bit more complicated than that. Im dynamically loading configs based on various request contexts (e.g. the user type, the section, and many other context facets). The config system then matches the defined context combinations, loads config overrides for the context match, falls back to any context value defaults, and finally falls back to common settings. JSON storage would make context definition *far* more cumbersome, defeating the purpose of looking for a simple solution.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've thought of that, and may resort to it. It feels dirty though :/

Comment: @AgmLauncher Yes, I agree it feels dirty, but would guarantee scalars for the config values and allow you to use `array_replace_recurisve()` in basic way w/o other contortions.

Comment: Similar to what @MichaelBerkowski proposed, you could use PHP or JSON serialization of the arraythat you want to treat as a full unit. Like `'modes' => '["single", "double", "round-robin"]'`

Comment: @AgmLauncher I know you had expressed concerns over a JSON-based conffig system, but I have shown a simple example below of how using such a system can in fact be pretty simple to maintain. At the heart of your problem is that you are currently defining everything as arrays (associative or numeric) and have no way to really handle nested arrays appropriately.  I think configs are really more like objects (with specific properties to be defined) and so if you think like objects, then I think you can overcome your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you an example of how using proper mix of objects and arrays would make this more straightforward.  Here I am showing you a JSON representation of a set of configurations as it is trivial to read a JSON config from a file or that has been set as string value to some variable and convert to PHP object using `json_decode()`.

```
{
    "tournaments": {
        "modes": [
            "single",
            "double",
            "round-robin"]
        ],
        "second_level_property": {
            "third_level_property": "foo"
        }
    },
    "first_level_property": "bar"
}
```

And let's say there are also two local config overrides as shown below and intended to be applied in the order shown below:

```
{
   "tournaments": {
        "modes": ["single"]
   }
}
```

And

```
{    
   "tournaments": {
        "modes": [
            "single",
            "round-robin"
        ],
        "second_level_property": null
   },
   "first_level_property": "baz"
}
```

The final config should look like this:

```
{
    "tournaments": {
        "modes": [
            "single",
            "round-robin"
        ],
        "second_level_property": null
    },
    "first_level_property": "baz"
}
```

Let's see how we can do this in PHP. First, we create a simple function to merge stdClass objects (the class of object that is created upon json_decode).

```
function stdClass_object_merge(stdClass $a, stdClass $b) {
    foreach ($b as $k => $v) {
        if ($v instanceof stdClass && isset($a->$k) && $a->$k instanceof stdClass) {
            // both reference and mergin objects have stdClass objects for this property
            // so we want to recursively merge these objects at this property
            $a->$k = stdClass_object_merge($a->$k, $v);
        } else {
            // this property may or may not be present on reference object
            // but in either case, we want to overwrite the value in reference object
            // with value from merging object
            $a->$k = $v;
        }
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Note that this function will only recurse upon cases where nested objects exist at the same property keys.  It will also always consider the values in the merging object (parameter $b) as authoritative, overwriting values at the same property in reference array or adding a property if missing on reference array.  This means that only stdClass objects can act as "nodes" in the configuration and that all other data types are treated as "leaves", giving the potential of cutting off a branch in the reference config if you pass a non-node value in the merging object where a node value exists in the reference object (like is done to the tournaments->second_level_property value in the merge example above)..

Usage then becomes very simple:

```
// read default config into stdClass object from file
$config = json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/default_config.json'));

// specify local override to configuration and merge that config to existing
$local_config_1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/local_config_1.json'));
$config = stdClass_object_merge($config, $local_config_1);

// merge another config    
$local_config_2 = json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/local_config_2.json'));
$config = stdClass_object_merge($config, $local_config_2);
```

Though I have a slight bias towards JSON based on it's flexible yes concise syntax, you can actually do basically what you are doing now in PHP-based definitions.  They just become a little more verbose.  An example of the default config above done in PHP would be like:

```
$config = new stdClass;
$config->tournaments->modes = [
    "single",
    "double",
    "round-robin"
]
$config->tournaments->second_level_property->third_level_property = 'foo';
$config->first_level_property = 'bar';
```

To me, this just doesn't seem to convey the overall structure of the config as well visually.  I am also biased against having config files that in themselves require code to set up the config and for being able to place configs into separate non-executable files which is very easy to do with the JSON approach.